# What Iterable will be used when working with Guava Iterables

Tags: java, iterator, guava, iterable

Given a class of the below structure:

```
public class Section extends IterableWidgetTemplate<Item>{

    private List<WebElement> items1;

    // other non iterable methods

    private int indexOf(final Item item) {

        int i = Iterables.indexOf(this, new Predicate<Item>() {

            . . . 

        });

        return i;
    }
```

where `Iterables` is a Guava `com.google.common.collect.Iterables` that, according to its documentation, contains static utility methods that operate on objects of type `Iterable`.

Now in the class that I described above, `this` is passed as an iterable to the `private int indexOf()` method.

**Questions:**

1. What am I going to iterate over in `this` object? Am I right in my assumption that the `Iterables` class will use the only iterable method  that is available in the object that is being passed to it? So in this case we have the `List<WebElement>` variable inside `this` object.
2. If the answer to 1. is "yes", what would have happened if the `Section` class had more than one iterable variable? Which one of them will be used for iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Iterables.indexOf()` takes as its first parameter an object which implements the `Iterable` interface. So, what `Iterables.indexOf()` iterates over is defined by the object passed in as a parameter, in your example the `Section` class. It's not using a variable however - it will call the `Iterable.iterator()` method on your `Section` object. It's not possible to have more than one of those methods so there can be no cases where there's confusion about what `Iterables.indexOf()` will iterate over.